# How to create a new instance of a function component in react js?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-hooks

i am trying to crate 2 image inputs in tow different location on my web app, by using the same component.
for examle:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
    <UploadImage/>
    <UploadImage/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

when i upload image in one component id overrides the other and show the image only on the first component.

the Upload Image component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function UploadImage(props) {
    const [image, setImage] = useState({ image: { preview: null, raw: null } });

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="upload-button">
                {image.preview ?
                    <img src={image.preview} style={{ maxWidth: 250, maxHeight: 250 }} alt={"image"} />
                    : <p className="text-center">Add image</p>
                }
            </label>
            <input
                type="file"
                id="upload-button"
                style={{ display: 'none', border: "5px solid red" }}
                onChange={e => setImage({
                    preview: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
                    raw: e.target.files[0]
                })}
                required
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further exactly what you are getting vs expecting? I'm having trouble understanding the question.

Comment: IDs have to be unique throughout the entire page. Put the `input` inside the `label` and you don't need an `id`. Or use an unique ID for each instance.

Comment: i want to upload 2 different images, but i get only one on the first component. doesnt matter which input i use to upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two inputs with id="upload-button", and two labels with htmlFor="upload-button". To behave as expected, your inputs should have unique ids so they can be reliably associated with the labels. Try passing unique values as props:

```
import React from "react";
import UploadImage from "./UploadImage";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <UploadImage inputId="image-upload-1" />
        <UploadImage inputId="image-upload-2" />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function UploadImage(props) {
  const [image, setImage] = useState({ image: { preview: null, raw: null } });

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={props.inputId}>
        {image.preview ? (
          <img
            src={image.preview}
            style={{ maxWidth: 250, maxHeight: 250 }}
            alt={"im"}
          />
        ) : (
          <p className="text-center">Add image</p>
        )}
      </label>
      <input
        type="file"
        id={props.inputId}
        style={{ display: "none", border: "5px solid red" }}
        onChange={e =>
          setImage({
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
            raw: e.target.files[0]
          })
        }
        required
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

working sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-christian-lb9d4?file=/src/UploadImage.js